# React couldn't find the module

Tags: reactjs

I have structured everything properly. But while compiling react keep on says module not found how to fix?

Module not found: Can't resolve 'ui-config/themes' in 'C:\Users\Goodwork\desktop\mihy-ui-framework\src'

this is my index file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material- 
ui/core/styles';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'ui-redux/store';
import './index.css';
import App from 'ui-views/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import themeObject from "ui-config/themes";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have configured webpack with `resolve` alias `ui-config`, it's not going to work because webpack looks for npm module called `ui-config` in `node_modules`.

To fix it,
Add to your webpack configuration the following:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
         'ui-config: 'relative-path-to-ui-config'
    }
}
```

alternatively, you can adjust the relative path in your import

```
import themeObject from "./ui-config/themes";
```

This is less optimal because eventually you'll end up struggeling with nested folders import '../../../../../' to find ui-config relative path.